# Refactoring major delegation usage in objective c

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, delegates, notifications

I'll first of all point out that i need advice and not code samples here. I know how to do the code...

I'm in a project where i feel the need to refactor a singleton class with (in my opinion) excessive use of delegations.

The state is that there are two classes, a singleton class "Manager" and another class "BackendManager". These two do most of the entire app's client-server communication as well as a some application logic.

The application is built up of a login, a menu, and some different functions. All these functions are completely independent, one could be a google map showing some business locations and another could be a calendar showing which meetings the user has. The only connection between these to functions is the login itself. This tells me for sure i need to take the code in the "Manager" and "BackendManager" classes related to the map and put in one place and the stuff for the calendar and put another place. And the same for all the other functions. Furthermore take the login and menu functionality and put somewhere else.

The thing i'm unsure about is whether or not to keep the delegation pattern for all these methods or replace some of it with notifications. The reason is that it's currently a big mess. The "Manager" has a "ManagerDelegate" protocol. It's obvious that this protocol has just gotten bigger and bigger in time. First it defines some login methods, for example

```
- (void)loginSuccess;
```

then it defines some maps functions

```
- (void)backendManagerDidLoadLocationTypes:(NSArray*)locationTypes;
- (void)backendManagerDidLoadLocations:(NSArray*)locations;
- (void)backendManagerDidLoadUserLocatios:(CLLocation*)location;
- (void)backendManagerDidLoadSearchResults:(NSArray*)results;
...
```

then some calendar functions

```
- (void)backendManagerDidLoadEvents:(NSArray*)events
- (void)backendManagerDidLoadEventTypes:(NSArray*)eventTypes
...
```

this of course goes on for all functions developed for the menu, as mentioned these are all independent of eachother.
You can imagine the "BackendManager" is just a convenience class for doing the actual fetching of data for rest services. It is done so the "BackendManager" roughly defines all the same methods as the "Manager", for example for the login functionality:

```
*Manager*
-(void)userLogin:(NSString*)username pin:(NSString*)pin
-(void)backendUserLogInSuccesCallBack:(BackendManager *)controller

*BackendManager*
-(void)userLogIn:(NSString*)username pin:(NSString*)pin

//Same for all other functions in both classes
```

So the "Manager" just calls the "BackendManager" and then the "BackendManager" will callback the "Manager" which will call the actual controller from where the call originated, for example LoginViewController. This makes the "Manager" superflous and just an annoying class to always go though when trying to understand the code.

Anyway, after walking through all this logic heres what i plan to do:

Build a model class for every function in the app.

- LoginModel
- MenuModel
- MapModel
- CalendarModel
- ...

These will all be singletons and i'll probably make a class to help doing the service-calls, but parsing of the response and other logic will be in the Models themselves for now.

So the question is - *does this sound like the right approach*, and am i right in thinking that it would be correct take the calls from "Manager" to the controllers, which are currently done using delegation and *change them to use notification pattern* (NSNotificationCenter), the calls corresponding to these would now be done in for example the LoginModel where is would throw a notification when logged in. The LoginViewController would then be listening for this notification.

The change to notifications is mostly based on the MVC model teached in the Stanford lessons, here i interpret that the delegation pattern is mostly used when communicating between Controllers and Views, and notifications of KVO is used when communicating from the Model to the controller.

This means that now, instead of sending userdata back from the "Manager" to the controller like

```
- (void)backendManagerDidLoadLocationTypes:(NSArray*)locationTypes;
```

above, I will throw a notification when they have been fetched and the controller will then fetch the locationtypes from the model using a different call. This would give me two calls in the Model, one to "update" the locationTypes (from server) and one to "get" them (locally). *So maybe these types of calls are the ones where i should stick to the delegation pattern?* Even though i'd rather use delegation only between views and controllers.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this question is more suited for [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), but I'll give you a quick answer here.

I like the approach of using notifications application level events. `UserDidLogin` and `LocationDidChange` are good examples. These events signal a change that all view controllers will want to know about.

I would avoid singletons. Usually view controllers can exchange data in `-prepareForSegue:sender:` or however you create your child view controllers.

As far as notifications for completed network events with update and get methods: I would avoid this. Always ask for the data using some async method (I prefer completion blocks), let the model take care of when to use a cached copy and when to update from the server.

I would also recommend splitting the control of access to model data from the model. People sometimes label this as a manger pattern, a factory pattern, or a data source pattern, but it all amounts to the same thing. Have a separate object which knows how to fetch data for one particle model. That object will return back fully formed model data.

For example, have a `locationTypeDataSource` object. The view controller requests location type data from this data source. The data source thens tells the view controller when the data is ready. This could be reported as a notification, KVO, or completion block.

Notification:

```
[self addObserverForName:LocationTypeDidLoad object:self.locationTypeDataSource queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    [self.tableView refreshData]; // or whatever
}

[self.locationTypeDataSource fetchLocationTypes];
```

KVO:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"locationTypeDataSource.locationTypes"]) {
        [self.tableView refreshData]; // or whatever
    }
}

[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"locationTypeDataSource.locationTypes" options:0 context:NULL];

[self.locationTypeDataSource fetchLocationTypes];
```

Completion Block:

```
[self.locationTypesDataSource fetchLocationTypesWithCompletion:^(NSArray *locationTypes, NSError *error){
    [self.tableView refreshData]; // or whatever
}];
```

The key is to use a separate object to fetch and prepare model data.

Comment: I'm reading your response as I should do a model thats more aware of the state of the application so the controllers don't have to tell the model whether or not it wants the data from the server or just locally. Woops - i'll do that :) I'm a really big fan of singletons when it comes to fetching data though. How about i make an object responsible for data fetching which would then be called by the Model whenever the controller asks for data. When it comes to application state logic, how would i hold this in the model if it's not a singleton and two controllers need the same state information?

Comment: With regards to splitting control of access to data from the model, i suppose that is why there originally were "Manager" and "BackendManager", so perhaps that part is not so bad, so behind the datadriven models i should do another class responsible for fetching data and handing it to the Model in a "fully formed model data" format. By that, do you mean i should fetch the json, parse it into object data and hand it to the model in that format? This could be done in the way i described in the comment above. I have a hard time imagining doing model work in a class thats not a singleton :(